# In python, what is the difference between slice with all the element and itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I saw a following line and I have difficulty understanding why someone would express it this way.

```
numbers = list(range(10))
numbers[:] = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0]
```

I attempted following line and it gives me the same result.

`numbers = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0]`

I understand that `[:]` means that its array with all the elements.

What is the purpose of attempting to assign to array with full element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numbers[:] = something` is known as *slice assignment*. It replaces the elements in the selected slice (the whole array in this case), with the elements to the right of the assignment.

`numbers = something` is regular assignment, which makes numbers point to `something`.

This example illustrates the differences:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
something = [4, 5, 6]

numbers = something
something[0] = 10
print(numbers) # [10, 5, 6]
```

Notice how we may have wanted to modify the `something` list, but we unexpectedly modified `numbers`! Because they point to the same list. However, things are different with slice assignment:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
something = [4, 5, 6]

numbers[:] = something
something[0] = 10
print(numbers) # [4, 5, 6]
```

`numbers` is still the same.

As pointed by user *Tomerikoo* in the comments, the slice's size doesn't have to match with whatever it's being replaced with. Which means the following is valid:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numbers[:] = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: example illustrated is extremely easy to understand. variable to variable assignment in python is reference update... so if I wanted to assign by value, I have to use the slice assignment... got it. thank you for the clear example.

Comment: worth noting that the size of `something` doesn't have to match the size of `numbers` (for the second case)

Comment: @Tomerikoo that's right, I'll edit my answer since some people may find it misleading

Comment: Not necesarily misleading, your answer is perfectly fine. I just thought that's a little detail worth mentioning for anyone reaching here :) great answer!